# Simple setting from form input to object attribute

Tags: jsf

```
<h:inputText value="#{myController.myString}" id="stg" />
<h:inputText value="#{myController.document.title}" id="title" />
<h:inputTextarea value="#{myController.document.subtitle}" id="subtitle" />
```

I can recover `myString` correctly, but `document` is always `null`. It has a default constructor. If I do a `Document document = new Document()` in `myController` then it is not null but `title` and `subtitle` are. Am I missing something?

---

**EDIT**

I thought my problem *might* not need additional information, but here it is:

**.xhtml**

```
<h:form id="ExampleForm" styleClass="myClass">
   <h:inputText value="#{myController.myString}" id="stg" />
   <h:inputText value="#{myController.document.title}" id="title" />
   <h:inputTextarea value="#{myController.document.subtitle}" id="subtitle" />
   <h:commandButton action="#{myController.readData()}" type="submit" value="Read"/>
</h:form>
```

Then I complete all the inputs in the form and click the button...

**Controller**

```
@Named(value = "myController")
@ViewScoped
public class MyController implements Serializable {

private String myString;
private Document document;
// getters and setters

public void readData() {
    System.out.println("String: " + myString);  // prints well
    System.out.println("Doc: " + document);  // prints null
    // System.out.println("Doc title: " + document.getTitle());  // prints null when I declare private Document document = new Document();
}

}
```

`Document` is a `Serializable` simple bean with `String title` and `subtitle` and the respective getters/setters.

---

**EDIT**

The problem seems to be solved thanks to BalusC pointer.

There have been different things that mixed up and made my code work incorrectly. First, I solve the problem with:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    document = new Document();
}

@PreDestroy
public void cleanup() {
    document = null;
}
```

Another mistake I had while researching the issue (and that's why some other things created errors) was I didn't specify `title` and `subtitle` in the `execute`:

```
<h:commandButton action="#{myController.readData()}" type="submit" value="Read">
 <f:ajax execute="@this title subtitle" />
</h:commandButton>
```

Comment: Please read [mcve] and http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: I used javax.faces.view.ViewScoped, which I think it is the correct one from what I read (instead of the javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped). Without ViewScoped I don't get the right results when I submit the form and it is reload

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand at all what is happening. I changed the object for multiple strings and it worked the 1st time, but then after that, the Strings are null all the time. Something is not working properly and I have no idea what. The code is a mirror of other code in the same page (with different IDs) and some attributes are get/set correctly and these new attributes are always null. Section [1] in the URL you posted seem OK to me. Still researching...

Comment: I think one problem for my last solution is that I included an ajax component and failed to put the right attributes:  `<f:ajax execute="@this" ...` inside execute. I think all the used IDs should be defined inside `<f:ajax execute="@this XXX YYY" ...`